# Linear Regression on random data

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas, machine-learning

Wrote a simple script to implement Linear regression and practice numpy/pandas. Uses random data, so obviously weights (thetas) have no significant meaning. Looking for feedback on

1. Performance
2. Python code style
3. Machine Learning code style

```
# Performs Linear Regression (from scratch) using randomized data
# Optimizes weights by using Gradient Descent Algorithm

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)

features = 3
trainingSize = 10 ** 1
trainingSteps = 10 ** 3
learningRate = 10 ** -2

randData = np.random.rand(trainingSize, features + 1)
colNames = [f'feature{i}' for i in range(1, features + 1)]
colNames.append('labels')

dummy_column = pd.Series(np.ones(trainingSize), name='f0')
df = pd.DataFrame(randData, columns=colNames)

X = pd.concat([dummy_column, df.drop(columns='labels')], axis=1)
y = df['labels']
thetas = np.random.rand(features + 1)

cost = lambda thetas: np.mean((np.matmul(X, thetas) - y) ** 2) / 2
dJdtheta = lambda thetas, k: np.mean((np.matmul(X, thetas) - y) * X.iloc[:, k])
gradient = lambda thetas: np.array([dJdtheta(thetas, k) for k in range(X.shape[1])])

# J(theta) before gradient descent
print(cost(thetas))

# Perform gradient descent
errors = np.zeros(trainingSteps)
for step in range(trainingSteps):
    thetas -= learningRate * gradient(thetas)
    errors[step] = cost(thetas)

# J(theta) after gradient descent
print(cost(thetas))

# Plots Cost function as gradient descent runs
plt.plot(errors)
plt.xlabel('Training Steps')
plt.ylabel('Cost Function')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

Your first two lines are nice comments. Consider putting them in a module docstring:

```
"""Performs Linear Regression (from scratch) using randomized data.

Optimizes weights by using Gradient Descent Algorithm.
"""
```

Consider adding random noise to something linear (or to some "wrong model" sine or polynomial), rather than to a constant.

```
np.random.seed(0)
```

Nice - reproducibility is Good.

```
trainingSize = 10 ** 1
trainingSteps = 10 ** 3
learningRate = 10 ** -2
```

These expressions are correct and clear. But why evaluate a FP expression when you could just write it as a literal? 1e1, 1e3, 1e-2. (This answer would apply in many languages, including Python. And yes, I actually prefer seeing the two integers written as floating point, even if that forces me to call int() on them.)

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) asks that you spell it `training_size`, and so on. Please run flake8, and follow its advice.

Your column names expression is fine. Consider handling the one-origin within the format expression:

```
col_names = [f'feature{i + 1}' for i in range(features)] + ['labels']
```

Specifying axis=1 is correct. I have a (weak) preference for explicitly spelling out: `axis='columns'`.

Consider hoisting the expression `np.matmul(X, thetas) - y`, so it is only evaluated once.

The three lambda expressions are fine, but they don't seem to buy you anything. Probably better to use `def` three times.

Ship it! But do consider noising a linear function, to make it easier to evaluate your results.